# Blender version discrepancy between older version and v3.2 - Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Eevee 3.2.2 vs Eevee 3.1.2

I dont understand why there is a lack of light reflections in the 3.2 version when I open the same .blend file in 3.2 and 3.1. I have checked the settings and they are all the same in render settings and in material settings.

[image: Eevee 3.2.2]

[image: Eevee 3.1.2]

Comment: my intuition says check normals, everything facing the camera should be blue

Comment: I checked normals, flipping them does nothing, same result. Still no reflections in 3.2.